# Converting MULTIPOLYGON field stored as text to geometry data type in PostGIS and plotting in QGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I have this column `Multipolygon` which has data stored in this format which is in `TEXT`:

`MULTIPOLYGON(-115.528984981578 51.2006109579736, -115.526434407604 51.1974145241941, -115.546464451 51.1829871710806, -115.550742857 51.1811679580806, -115.553744470846 51.1774015011275, -115.555832234 51.1721837870805, -115.554786455 51.1622000020805, -115.555224178 51.1614472730805, -115.555944264 51.1610654680805, -115.562343333 51.1605351540804, -115.56378839 51.1627737510805, -115.56474867 51.1633405150805, -115.565514534 51.1637801920805, -115.566251065 51.1640867590805, -115.569573964129 51.1647997677008, -115.590143361 51.1644759770805, -115.592124654 51.1682185420805, -115.581962807 51.1831234430806, -115.572065302636 51.1872314983322, -115.563133431 51.1914924190807, -115.561930802 51.1918677000807, -115.535909179968 51.2067716415175, -115.528984981578 51.2006109579736)`

How can I convert this column data-type into geometry data `EPSG:4326` type so that I can plot this in QGIS?

when I do this:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(multipolygon,4326) FROM transient.crea_multipolygon_data;
```

I get an error:

> [XX000] ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry Hint:
>   "MULTIPOLYGON(-115.528984981578 " <-- parse error at position 31
>   within geometry

But the same Multipolygon text when I plot over here https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html looks great so not sure what's going on:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html), if you use `MULTIPOLYGON`, your SQL in PostGIS lack of brackets as part of a multipolygon is into two brackets.

Here is a working code:

`SELECT ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((-115.528984981578
51.2006109579736, -115.526434407604 51.1974145241941, -115.546464451 51.1829871710806, -115.550742857 51.1811679580806, -115.553744470846 51.1774015011275, -115.555832234 51.1721837870805, -115.554786455 51.1622000020805, -115.555224178 51.1614472730805, -115.555944264 51.1610654680805, -115.562343333 51.1605351540804, -115.56378839 51.1627737510805, -115.56474867 51.1633405150805, -115.565514534 51.1637801920805, -115.566251065 51.1640867590805, -115.569573964129 51.1647997677008, -115.590143361 51.1644759770805, -115.592124654 51.1682185420805, -115.581962807 51.1831234430806, -115.572065302636 51.1872314983322, -115.563133431 51.1914924190807, -115.561930802 51.1918677000807, -115.535909179968 51.2067716415175, -115.528984981578 51.2006109579736)))', 4326);`

Comment: This is actually not multipolygon but polygon, so `POLYGON(( ... ))` with double brackets would be also OK.